# "top" command can not support chinese characters in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: character

I found a problem, can anyone help to solve?

My Ubuntu "top" command cannot display Chinese characters correctly. It's using unrecognized characters, see the below:

joe@joe-us:~/app$ top -bc -n 1|grep home
1989 joe       20   0 34760 2564 2148 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 /usr/lib/gvfs//gvfs-fuse-daemon -f /home/joe/.gvfs
9577 joe       20   0  217m  40m  19m S    0  1.0   3:01.42 /home/joe/��?�?�/�?� sublime_text �??�?��?�
13885 joe       20   0  5828  820  732 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 grep --color=auto home
joe@joe-us:~/app$

---

For the same process, command "ps" works OK.

joe@joe-us:~/app$ ps -ef|grep home
joe       1989     1  0 10:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//gvfs-fuse-daemon -f /home/joe/.gvfs
joe       9577     1  1 12:00 ?        00:03:01 /home/joe/桌面/到 sublime_text 的链接
joe      13883 12362  0 16:36 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto home

---

My system can support Chinese characters well now, here is the environment
joe@joe-us:~/app$ echo $LANGUAGE
zh_CN:zh
joe@joe-us:~/app$

joe@joe-us:~/桌面$ ls
aliedit.sh  github  github~  keeper.php  Logo  root  root~  到 sublime_text 的链接
joe@joe-us:~/桌面$

joe@joe-us:~$ echo $TERM
xterm

---

right display:/home/joe/桌面/到 sublime_text 的链接
wrong display:/home/joe/��?�?�/�?� sublime_text �??�?��?�

Thank you very much!